# Дело в шляпе

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать, откуда пошла поговорка "дело в шляпе".
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение восходит  к  старинному обычаю все  спорные  дела  решать  жеребьевкой: в шляпу  бросали   монеты  или другие  мелкие  предметы, один  из  которых был  с  меткой. Кому  посчастливилось  достать  такой  предмет, тот  и  победил  в  споре, у  него ДЕЛО  В  ШЛЯПЕ.
По другой  версии, фразеологизм  связан  с  обычаем  должностных лиц, разбиравших  разные дела, брать  взятки, которые  клали  в  головной  убор.

Comment: Взятка, сто пудов! Простейший способ добиться нужного решения в суде))) Это я в теоретическом плане рассуждаю...

Answer (score 2):

Википедия даёт несколько версий происхождения выражения
   Чиновники, разбиравшие дела, брали взятки в шляпы. Мздоимство — древнейший и хорошо зарекомендовавший себя способ разрешения вопросов в инстанциях: раз чиновник взял взятку — значит, дело будет разобрано в пользу мзду давшего. 
   В старину, когда почты еще не существовало, документы доставляли гонцы. Чтобы не потерять важные бумаги, они зашивали их под подкладку шапки или шляпы. Таким образом, самые важные «дела» находились в шляпах.
   При Иване Грозном некоторые судебные дела решались жребием, а жребий тянули из шляпы судьи. Иными словами, все дело решалось в шляпе. Эта версия многими лингвистами признается сомнительной: слово «шляпа» пришло в русский язык несколько позже.
   Из шляпы тянули жребий не только судьи. И действительно, зачем к ним идти — и далеко, и хлопотно, и грамотность требуется, и тяжба будет долго тянуться, и деньги платить, — если можно разрешить все вопросы на месте и по-деловому быстро. Сергей Максимов, автор книги «Крылатые слова», пишет, что именно таким способом выясняли свои претензии древние евреи, этот же обычай распространился и по Руси и соблюдался довольно долго. Кто вытягивал счастливую «бирку», тот и получал право на какое-то дело — продажу товара, приобретение чего-либо, получение заказа или что-либо иное, задуманное в жребии. Шляпа, таким образом, давала надежду на что-то задуманное. Наоборот, «прошляпить» — значит, потерять эту надежду, упустить возможность.

Comment: ну вообще-то это только поторят уже сказанное. 
К тому же Соврешенное невозможное предположение о заимствовании выражения от дреаних евреев только подрывает доверие к источнику.  
Хотя у меня к нему веры и так нет.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое ощущение, что и само слово "шляпа" и тем более выражение получило распространеие гораздо позже всех этих жеребьевок и взяток...
В качестве версии (не опровергая сказанного) предположу, что когда из шляпы достают кроликов, то дело, понятно, в шляпе.

Answer (score 0):

```
                             Происхождеие фразеологизма
```

Несколько столетий назад, когда почты в теперешнем ее виде не су­ществовало, все сообщения доставлялись гонцами на лошадях. По проезжим дорогам бродило тогда немало разбойников, и сумка с па­кетом могла привлечь внимание грабителей. Поэтому важные бу­маги, или, как их раньше называли, дела, зашивали под подклад­ку шляпы или шапки.

По другой, более распростаненной версии, дело в шляпе означало принятие решения по спорному вопросу  жребием. Самое подходящее место для жребия, которое всегда под рукой – шляпа.

Более правдоподобно выглядит объяснение выражения дело в шляпе, когда речь идет о даче взятки. Получаемые деньги, то есть мзду чиновнику за принятие нужного решения, тот сразу прятал в шляпу, за подкладку шляпы.

Данный фразеологизм означает то, что все хорошо, все в порядке. Об успешном завершении, исходе чего-либо.

Answer (score 0):

**В словарике для начальной школы есть  фразеологизм "дело в шляпе"** и приводится версия  о споре: п**рав тот, чей предмет достали первым из шляпы.**

В то же время не объясняется, **откуда такая уверенность в благоприятном исходе.** Это, как я считаю, недоработка словаря: как обычно, дети ничего не поймут, а спросить у строгого учителя побоятся. Поэтому нужны хотя бы предположения на этот счет.

Мне кажется, что в этом случае дело отдавалось **на решение высшим силам,** которые уж точно **знают правильный ответ**. А если искатель уверен в своей правоте, то он не сомневается в том, что **шляпа это "подтвердит".**

Поэтому первоначальный смысл фразеологизма, как я думаю, **в уверенности в чём-либо** (я уверен, что прав), а потом уже  ― **в положительном исходе дела:** я уверен, что всё будет благополучно, так как для этого есть веские основания,  иначе быть не может, и скоро мы убедимся в этом.

**Примеры:**

Меченов его старый приятель, они из одного города, так что ― **дело в шляпе**… [Юрий Трифонов. Предварительные итоги (1970)]

― Все. Считай, **дело в шляпе**, ― подытожила Николь. ― **Откуда у тебя такая уверенность**? [Вацлав Михальский. Одинокому везде пустыня (2003)]